# Issue with Microsoft chat bot giving double responses to a question instead of just 1 time that i have instructed it to do

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, speech, microsoft-speech-api, microsoft-speech-platform

I am currently using micro soft's speech studio to create a simple chat bot. For all my questions, I need to add a confirmation rule to ask if they need further assistance getting to the location they are looking for. However after it gets to the last part of the speech command it keeps saying the speech 2 times instead of just that once. For example, for this question on where chambers b is for example, it will say the speech response twice instead of just that once that it used to output just 2 days back.

[the example sentences page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uagbu.png)

[this is my confirmation command in the speech studio to ask whether they need assistance getting to the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRJJ0.png)
[this is my successful command assuming the user says yes during the confirmation stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMJx0.png)

However the issue came about just yesterday when I was testing the chatbot. I got this output during testing: "Sure, please follow me now" twice instead of just once that I needed.
[this is what came up during the testing phase. As you can see it said sure please follow me now 2 times instead of just that 1 time that I needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK0lN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out.

The configuration in the screenshots look OK.

I created a confirmation example to verify the behavior and I was not able to reproduce this with the windows client (same you used in your screenshots).

Here is the sample app you can import to try it out.

```js
{
  "entityResolver": {
    "searchConfiguration": {
      "maxEdits": 0
    },
    "type": "internal",
    "isGenerated": true
  },
  "minIntentConfidence": 0.4,
  "highIntentConfidence": 0.8,
  "lgTemplates": [
    "# FallbackResponse",
    "- Add your fallback message here",
    "# TestCommand-MyNumber",
    "- what number?",
    "# TestCommand-27dfe650040311ebb2dccf4459b3ff8b",
    "- confirmed.",
    "# TestCommand-3228f4d0040311ebb2dccf4459b3ff8b",
    "- denied.",
    "# TestCommand-4ea19f40040311ebb2dccf4459b3ff8b",
    "- sure?"
  ],
  "type": "BaseLanguage",
  "recognizer": {
    "application": "",
    "isStaging": false,
    "versionId": "0.1",
    "type": "luis"
  },
  "speechOutput": {
    "font": "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, Aria24kRUS)",
    "locale": "en-US"
  },
  "webEndpoints": [],
  "globalParameters": [],
  "commands": [
    {
      "name": "FallbackCommand",
      "completionStrategy": "OnRequiredParameters",
      "parameters": [],
      "rules": [],
      "completionRules": [
        {
          "name": "DefaultResponse",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "True"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "SpeechResponse",
              "response": {
                "type": "Template",
                "templateName": "# FallbackResponse"
              }
            }
          ],
          "postExecutionState": "None"
        }
      ],
      "triggeringExamples": [
        "> - You can start sentences with '>' to add comments.",
        "> - You can also use parameters by adding the name of the parameter within curly braces, i.e.",
        ">     Set an alarm to {YourDateParameterName}",
        ">   Where YourDateParameterName is the name of a parameter defined in the 'Parameters' section.",
        "Help",
        "Help me",
        "What can you do?",
        "How can I start?",
        "Hello",
        "Hi"
      ],
      "multiTurnExamples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "TestCommand",
      "completionStrategy": "OnRequiredParameters",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "MyNumber",
          "type": {
            "name": "Number"
          },
          "elicitResponse": {
            "type": "Template",
            "templateName": "# TestCommand-MyNumber"
          }
        }
      ],
      "rules": [
        {
          "name": "Confirm command",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "AllRequiredParameters"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "SpeechResponse",
              "response": {
                "type": "Template",
                "templateName": "# TestCommand-4ea19f40040311ebb2dccf4459b3ff8b"
              }
            }
          ],
          "nextTurnExpectations": [
            {
              "type": "Confirmation"
            }
          ],
          "postExecutionState": "WaitForInput"
        },
        {
          "name": "Confirmation succeeded",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "SuccessfulConfirmation"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "SpeechResponse",
              "response": {
                "type": "Template",
                "templateName": "# TestCommand-27dfe650040311ebb2dccf4459b3ff8b"
              }
            }
          ],
          "nextTurnExpectations": [],
          "postExecutionState": "ReadyForCompletion"
        },
        {
          "name": "Confirmation denied",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "DeniedConfirmation"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "SpeechResponse",
              "response": {
                "type": "Template",
                "templateName": "# TestCommand-3228f4d0040311ebb2dccf4459b3ff8b"
              }
            }
          ],
          "nextTurnExpectations": [],
          "postExecutionState": "CompleteCommand"
        }
      ],
      "completionRules": [
        {
          "name": "Done",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "True"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [],
          "nextTurnExpectations": [],
          "postExecutionState": "CompleteCommand"
        }
      ],
      "triggeringExamples": [
        "number {MyNumber}",
        "my number is {MyNumber}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is a sample output with the windows client.

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2bao.png)

Hope this help! o.w. If you could clone your application and provide a stripped-down version with the failure and we'll be happy to help you troubleshoot further.